# How to set default image using vuex store?

Tags: image, vue.js, vuex

I wanted to set default image for the user in vuex.
Here is my vuex store

```
state:{
default_image: "../assets/images/users/1.jpg"
},
getters:{
 Image:state=>state.default_image,
}
```

Then the App.vue

```
<template>
<img src=this.image alt="alt" />
</template>

<script>
import {mapGetters} from 'vuex'
export default {
      ...mapGetters({
                image:'Image',
            }),
}
```

but it does not work, the template does not see the image, but if I put the path directly in src without using vuex everything works. Can't figure out what's the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with the required please:

```
:src="`require(${image})`"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<img :src="image" alt="alt" />
```

Comment: still it does not see the image